# SAS : row difference

Tags: date, sas, rows

I have to calculate date difference between first date at time = 0 and the dates after. I also have one variable = factor which has 2 categories : one ; two.

For example, here is one date :

```
A             B       TIME
10/11/2016    one      T0
17/11/2016    two      T0
05/01/2017    one      T1
28/02/2017    two      T1
06/07/2017    one      T2
05/09/2017    two      T2
```

I would like to calculate the difference between T0 and the dates for B="one" and B="two" in order to obtain :

```
DIFF
0
0
56 
103
238
292
```

Calculating the diff as follows :

```
56 = T1-T0 for "one" = 05/01/2017 - 10/11/2016  
103 = T1-T0 for "two" = 28/02/2017 - 17/11/2016   
238 = T2-T0 for "one" = 06/07/2017 - 10/11/2016
292 = T2-T0 for "two" = 05/07/2017 - 17/11/2016
```

Could you help me do it in SAS?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to pull out the TIME='T0' records and merge them back with the other records.

First let's convert your table into a dataset.

```
data have ;
  input b $ Time $ date :yymmdd.;
  format date yymmdd10.;
cards;
one T0 2016-11-10
two T0 2016-11-17
one T1 2017-01-05
two T1 2017-02-28
one T2 2017-07-06
two T2 2017-09-05
;
```

Now let's re-order it so that we can merge by the grouping variable, `B`.

```
proc sort ;
  by b time ;
run;
```

Here is a way to merge the data with itself.

```
data want ;
  merge have(where=(time ne 'T0')) 
        have(keep=time b date rename=(time=time0 date=date0) where=(time0='T0'))
  ;
  by b ;
  diff = date - date0;
  drop time0;
run;
```

Results:

```
Obs     b     Time          date         date0    diff

 1     one     T1     2017-01-05    2016-11-10      56
 2     one     T2     2017-07-06    2016-11-10     238
 3     two     T1     2017-02-28    2016-11-17     103
 4     two     T2     2017-09-05    2016-11-17     292
```

Comment: Thanks Tom. I will test it on my data ... Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

There are of course several ways to do this. Below are two alternatives. The first selects the first A for each B and merges this with the original data in a SQL-step. The second uses a DATA-step and by groups. The first A within each B is saved as firsttime, and retained so it can be used to calculate the difference.

```
data test;
    input A  ddmmyy10. @12 B $3.;
    format A ddmmyy10.;
datalines;
10/11/2016 one
17/11/2016 two
05/01/2017 one
28/02/2017 two
06/07/2017 one
05/09/2017 two
;

/*  Alt 1*/
proc sql;
    create table test2 as 
    select t1.*, t1.A-t2.A as time
    from test as t1 left join (select B, min(A) as A from test group by 1) as t2
        on t1.B=t2.B
    order by A;

/* Alt 2*/
proc sort data=test;
    by B A;
run;

data test3;
    set test;
        by B;
    retain firsttime;
    if first.B then firsttime=A;
    time=A-firsttime;
    drop firsttime;
run;
```